# disable masking for input type password

Tags: html, types, passwords, masking

Is there a way to disable masking for  ?

I tried `input[type='password'][name='TxtPassword]{ -webkit-text-security: none !important;}`

But  this didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: security ... none important ... sounds risky.

Comment: how about input `type=text`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the type using JavaScript. Setting type to `text` will show the text.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var textbox = document.querySelector("input");
    if (textbox.type == "password") {
        textbox.type = "text";
    } else {
        textbox.type = "password";
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="password" value="password" />
<button>Toggle type</button>
```